# Exposing Java method (with parameters) in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to expose Java method via Scala (more details on original java method - it is coming from [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#resume(java.util.Collection)))

This is original Java method:

```
public void resume(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

How to expose and pass parameters to a method in Scala and which Scala collection to use in this case? 
I have something like:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{KafkaConsumer, OffsetAndMetadata}
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition

import collection.mutable.Map
import collection.JavaConverters._

//initialise consumer:
var consumer = createKafkaConsumer(config, subscriptions)

//accept a scala.collection.mutable.Map here
def commitSync(offsets: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer) = {
    //and then convert it to a java
    consumer.resume(offsets.asJava)
}
```

Also, how to call (and pass parameters) to this method in Scala?
Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call the `resume` function? What have you tried?

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Comment: That all looks OK. Are you getting an error? What is the problem?

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: It complains `Type ArrayBuffer takes Type parameter` (in IDE when typed). I am trying to expose Java method via scala so that someone who is using library in scala can access Java method. In order to access Java Kafka method - I need to create Scala Method that will 1) Have good signature (not sure yet which one is good)  2) Make working example - call to that Scala method with parameters and 3) Make sure that it can call underlaying Java Kafka method with appropriate arguments passed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Ah right. Try this:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition

import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import collection.JavaConverters._

//initialise consumer:
val consumer = createKafkaConsumer(config, subscriptions) // Make this a val!

//accept a scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer here
def commitSync(offsets: ArrayBuffer[TopicPartition]) = {
  //and then convert it to a java
  consumer.resume(offsets.asJava)
}
```

It looks like the ArrayBuffer needs to contain `TopicPartition` instances, in order to convert that to a *Java* collection of `TopicPartition` for the `resume` call to work.

In *Scala* you *always* need to enter the type parameters of a collection.

I assume you know what a `TopicPartition` instance looks like, since that's part of *Kafka*. (Read the [API Docs if you're unsure](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/TopicPartition.html).)

In order to call the `commitSync` function, you would need an `ArrayBuffer` of `TopicPartition` instances. For example:

```scala
val topics: ArrayBuffer[TopicPartition] = ArrayBuffer(
  new TopicPartition("sometopicname", somePartitionNum),
  new TopicPartition("someothertopic", someOtherPartitionNum),
  // etc.
)
commitSync(topics)
```

Comment: Thanks! How would a call (signature) for this method look like?

Comment: @Joe I edited the answer to show how it should be called.

Comment: Thanks! I see `TopicPartition​(java.lang.String topic, int partition)` so then  should it be `val topics: ArrayBuffer[TopicPartition] = ('mytopicname', partition-num)` pattern (just trying to fill in the blanks above ->  `//....`)?

Comment: @Joe Added further clarification to the answer. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: What was the reason using `ArrayBuffer` and not `List`?

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure what you mean. You used an `ArrayBuffer` in your original problem, so I simply used the same data structure. The collection that suits you best will depend upon what how you're populating the set of partitions that you require.

Comment: I am just trying to expose Java method inside Scala.. So no requirements as for Data Structure (I put it there as example but not sure if is correct one).. All I want is to expose method from Java into Scala 'as is' (including correct data structure). What would be your suggestion?

Comment: @Joe You use the word "expose" in relation to _Java_ often, but everything in _Java_ is available in _Scala_ with almost no effort. A _Java_ function is a _Scala_ function too; there's no need to _expose_ anything! However, because it has different design goals, _Scala_ programs typically use different collections from those in _Java_. You can still use _Java_ collections in _Scala_, but they're not as nice. The simplest approach, once you've decided on the collection you need, is to use the _Java_ variant, so that you can pass it unmodified to this function. (Continued in next comment...)

Comment: @Joe So, how do you decide what type of collection you want? That will depend upon what you're trying to do. Usage and efficiency considerations will determine that for you. Here's a link to a [guide that might help you](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-choose-collection-class-scala-cookbook). As in my other answer, I strongly recommend that you read a good _Scala_ book, such as [_Programming in Scala, 3rd Edition_](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed) or [_Functional Programming in Scala_](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala).

Comment: @Joe _Scala_ is not a simple language, at first glance, but it has some basic principles that make it very concise, elegant, powerful and easy to use—once you're familiar with it. I have been using it as my primary programming language for almost 10 years, and I'm still learning. I would recommend that you try to forget about _Java_ the language—it's irrelevant to you as a _Scala_ programmer. However, _Java_ libraries are _Scala_ libraries, and you should think of them as such. Good luck on your _Scala_ journeys!

Comment: Thanks Mike! I already picked up a book about scala and diving in.. At this moment just want to support the project in Kafka for users who use scala and since Kafka libraries are written in Java - want to make sure how to provide same functionalities in Scala. Sometimes it is not re-creatging methods but to explain to users (who know even less than me) about how to use specific methods in Scala so that they can call Kafka and do actions that they want.. right now for understanding each method in Kafka takes time and also how to use it with scala. Thanks for guidance..